# Write an Algorithm that Outputs Whether a Number is a Perfect Square

Tags: algorithms

Write an algorithm that takes an arbitrary natural number and returns a boolean of whether the number is a perfect square. Sketch a flowchart of the algorithm.

My approach is that a natural number $n$ is a perfect square if and only if we are able to find a natural number $i$ where $i < n$ such that $n / i - i = 0$ and write an algorithm with this information.

Comment: Yeah this is homework.by chart I mean expressing the algorithm in terms of arrows and actions.fluchart something like that

Comment: my Idea was that a natural n is complete square if and only if we can find natural i less than n such that expression (n/i -i)becomes zero and write algorithm by this information

Comment: So you already have a solution. What other question do you have then? You can edit the question and update it.

Comment: There are many online resources on this problem. A simple google search will give you the answer. And, please do not put clarifications in the comment you can update the question.

Answer (score 4):

The initial approach of finding a natural number $i$ that satisfies the condition $n / i - i = 0$ may be correct, but inconvenient as we will need to handle floating point division. An alternative condition would be to use the definition of a perfect square itself, $i \cdot i = n$.

The initial approach of checking each natural number $i$ where $i < n$ means that we need to check $n$ different numbers, yielding time complexity of $O(n)$. Can we do better, faster? We will write an example with $n = 9$ and see if we can make some observations:

$i = 1 \rightarrow 1 \cdot 1 < 9$

$i = 2 \rightarrow 2 \cdot 2 < 9$

$i = 3 \rightarrow 3 \cdot 3 = 9$

$i = 4 \rightarrow 4 \cdot 4 > 9$

$i = 5 \rightarrow 5 \cdot 5 > 9$

$i = 6 \rightarrow 6 \cdot 6 > 9$

$i = 7 \rightarrow 7 \cdot 7 > 9$

$i = 8 \rightarrow 8 \cdot 8 > 9$

You might have noticed that after $i = 3$, $i$ will always be larger than the required number, meaning $i \cdot i > n$. In fact, $i$ will always be larger than the required number when $i \cdot i > n$, since $i$ will be larger than $\sqrt n$. We can skip those cases and replace the initial condition of $i < n$ with $i \cdot i ≤ n$. Doing so, we will only need to check $\sqrt n$ different numbers, yielding time complexity of $O(\sqrt n)$.

But can we do even better? You might have noticed from the previous example that before $i = 3$, $i$ will always be smaller than the required number, meaning $i \cdot i < n$. How might we make use of this monotonically increasing property? The same way you might have searched a phone book: look in the middle, see if the name you are looking for is there, or discard the first half, or discard the second half, repeat!

Through all possible $i$ between $1$ and $9$, we might check the middle $i = 5$ and find that $9 < 5 \cdot 5$, naturally we discard the second half. Through all possible $i$ between $1$ and $5$, we might again check the middle $i = 3$ and find that $9 = 3 \cdot 3$, and conclude our binary search. Since we are repeatedly dividing the search space by half, this yields the optimal time complexity of $O(log\ n)$.

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the square root of n, round to the nearest integer, and check whether the square equals n.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest a simple algorithm. The psuedocode is below.

```
for (i=1; ((i*i) < n); i++); // this for loop will exit when i*i becomes >= n
if ((i*i) == n) {
    return 1; // true
} else {
    return 0; // false
}
```